# Having Listener in new Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, return, keylistener, runnable

I'm trying to place my `KeyListener` in a new `Thread` called `Keys` in my project because my main thread is already in a loop. So I want this method to return a `boolean` if the key is pressed or not. I'm pretty new to Java so sorry if that is just a dumb mistake.

**Thread:**

```
public class Keys implements KeyListener, Runnable {

    private boolean w = false;
    //private boolean ... same stuff

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        //nothing in here ;)
    }
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        //set right boolean true = no problem
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        //set right boolean false = no problem
    }

    public void run() {
        //nothing to do here
    }

    public boolean isWPressed(){
        return w;
    }
    //public boolean is...() [more of them.]
}
```

I would appreciate an example. That's the best way I learn.

Comment: 1. Classes don't return values. 2. Are you planning on calling `isXPressed()` for each key on the keyboard in your main thread? 3. Why not handle your key press in the method that was designed to do that? (`keyPressed`)? 4. What, exactly, is your question?

Comment: 1. Fixed. 2. Only for 4 Keys. 3. Tell me how 4. How can i get my Listener to work.

Comment: 5 the listener is called from the GUI's thread... if the processing in the listener is heavy, THEN you should launch it in a different thread so the GUI's thread does not get stuck.

Comment: Could you please give me examples? As I said, I'm pretty new to Java and can't understand exactly what you mean.

Comment: @SJuan76 it's not heavy

Comment: @JulianE. What would you like to happen when an appropriate key is pressed? This is what you should do in `keyPressed()`. Is `keyPressed` not getting called? Can we see the rest of your code?

Comment: Your class implements Runnable, and it has a run() method that does nothing?  That's a pretty strong code smell.

Comment: It seems you've got a completely wrong idea of how concurrency works in java. You should better read some tutorials first, e.g. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Listener is not called by your program. Swing calls the Listener when an apropiate event happens. For example: say we write a `KeyListener` for a `TextField`. If the user starts typing in this `TextField`, Swing will call the corresponding methods in the listener. So, the Listener is called by Swing, not by your code and thus you cannot write it for an own thread. This principle is also known as [Hollywood principle ("Don't call us, we call you!") (`wikipedia.org`)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Hollywood_principle). [This link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/) gives a good introduction to Events and Listener in Swing.

**EDIT**

As mentioned by SJuan76, we are able to launch seperate threads FROM the listener to do stuff we want them to.

Comment: So I can put my `KeyListener` in the Thread that is already in use with a while loop and it can create a new Thread/send something to my Thread?

Comment: No. The KeyListener is only an object. The methods of this object are called by the Java VM, which is running in a seperate thread alltogether, as mentioned by SJuan76. Before you try threading things in Java, focus on understanding listeners and events. Just one step at a time.

Comment: @JulianE. objects cannot be "put into" a thread! Instead the methods of an object are invoked by a certain thread. If you pass your key listener to a new thread instance (by calling `new Thread(new Keys())`), the `run` method of your class will be called by this new thread when it has been started. That's all. There is no magic that calls your key listener methods then automatically.

Comment: Is it possible to give me a short example code how I could do it?

Answer (score 1):

The Java Key Listener that you are using runs on it's own thread already. There is no need to try to put it in it's own thread.

Reading into the comments however, if you want to start a new thread when a key is pressed for example, you could. The following is how you might go about it:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(this, "Keyboard Thread");
```

Hope this helped!